# Laravel - How to modify column with migration?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I added `foreign key` to my table, but forgot to make it `nullable()`.
How can I change column now? As I understand I have to create new migration file with `--table` flag and add something like: `->nullable()->change();`
Correct?

Comment: Did you migrate on the server or just now?

Comment: @KhaldounNd just now. I created separate migration. Now need to add doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to create another `migration` or you `rollback` your previous migration.
There is an example on the Laravel page for modifying columns:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->change();
});
```

See also this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns

If you prefer a `rollback` see this link.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#rolling-back-migrations